# how to run a script on server before shutdown or reboot

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services

I want to send  server logs to s3 bucket directly.

I created a script for that and this will run once in a day and now I want that it will run when the server is going to reboot or shutdown.

So for this, I kept this script into `/etc/init.d` directory and created a symbolic link in `/etc/rc6` and `/etc/rc0` directory.

Why it's not running when the server is rebooting or shutting down?

```
sudo tar -czvf otaaccess.tar.gz /var/log/nginx/access.log
INSTANCE=$(cat /var/tmp/aws-mon/instance-id)
sudo aws s3 cp /home/ec2-user/otaaccess.tar.gz s3://hubbleserver-logs/ota/access/`date +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M`-$INSTANCE.log
sudo truncate -s 0 /var/log/nginx/access.log
sudo rm /home/ec2-user/otaaccess.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the "secret" is to create a lock file like I did in the following init script. After that lock file is created,  it should work in case system gets rebooted.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Description: abc script
# chkconfig:    3 99 01

mylog="/var/log/abc.log"

case "$1" in
  start)
    touch /var/lock/subsys/abc
    ;;
  stop)
    echo "Before init 6" > $mylog
    date >> $mylog
    ;;
esac
```

---- Some commands -----

```
# chkconfig --add abc
# chkconfig --list abc
    abc             0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:off   5:off   6:off
```

Answer (score 0):

With systemctl I would use a `oneshot` service type:

```
nano /etc/systemd/system/stop.service
```

.

```
[Unit]
Description=Stop service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStop=myStopScript.sh
User=administrator

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Register:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable cleanstopvnc
```